# How do I set platform options with Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter?

Tags: database, zend-framework2, adapter, firebird

I create my adapter like this;

```
new Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter(array(
                'driver'   => 'Pdo_Firebird',
                'database' => $dbParams['hostname'] . ':' . $dbParams['database'],
                'username' => $dbParams['username'],
                'password' => $dbParams['password'],
                'platform_options' => array('quote_identifiers' => false),
            ));
```

However, platform options do not get set. What's the correct way to set platform options?

Comment: Please do not ask questions in a comment. Just update the question.

Comment: Did this may help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123251/database-connection-with-firebird-adapter-in-zend-framework

Comment: No that is a ZF1 question, this is a ZF2 question.

Comment: 'driver'         => 'Pdo',
'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=zf2tutorial;host=localhost'


http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/tutorial.dbadapter.html

Comment: Are you using 2.4.x or 2.5.x version of ZF2?